# Can a Druid take Improved Natural Attack for use with Wild Shape?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, wild-shape

The question arises because someone referenced the wording on the feat's prerequisites, they said the Druid would need a natural attack *all* the time to qualify:

**Improved Natural Attack:**
Attacks made by one of this creature’s natural attacks leave vicious wounds.
Prerequisite: Natural weapon, base attack bonus +4.

If the Druid does not have a natural attack in his regular form, does this prohibit taking the feat? I perceived it as similar to taking ranks in the Fly skill--you just have to have access to a form that can do it--but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 9):

From [the Paizo SRD on Feat Prerequisites](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/feats.html#feats):

> A character can't use a feat if he loses a prerequisite, but he does not lose the feat itself. If, at a later time, he regains the lost prerequisite, he immediately regains full use of the feat that prerequisite enables.

It appears that you can take the feat, but can't use it while not having a natural weapon. You regain the benefits when you regain the prerequisites.

Answer (score 2):

On [Feats](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/feats.html) on Prerequisites says

> Some feats have prerequisites. Your character must have the indicated ability score, class feature, feat, skill, base attack bonus, or other quality designated in order to select or use that feat. A character can gain a feat at the same level at which he gains the prerequisite.

That is, first, a creature must meet a feat's prerequisite to *select* the feat *at all*. Thereafter, a creature need not *always* meet that feat's prerequisite to *keep* the feat, but the creature must meet the feat's prerequisite to realize the feat's benefit.

Further, [Character Advancement](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/character-advancement/) on Advancing Your Character says, "A character advances in level as soon as he earns enough experience points to do so—typically, this occurs at the end of a game session, when your GM hands out that session’s experience point awards." Thus if a druid meets the prerequisite for the feat [Improved Natural Attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/monster-feats/improved-natural-attack) while using the supernatural ability wild shape right as that druid's about to advance a level, the druid may meet the prerequisite for the feat Improved Natural Attack and he can select the feat, but the druid will only be able to make use of the feat when he *meets* the feat's prerequisite… so usually *not* while in his natural form.

Comment: Yeah, this was what I understood from that reference. So, this would also mean that if I had +1 dex from an armor, I could pick a 13 dex prerequisite feat if I had a base dex of 12, but if I removed the armor, I would lose the feat until I put it on again. Is that correct?

Comment: @JohnHamilton Yes. But you'd need that +1 to have taken the feat in the first place. A creature can't just pick high-powered feats and hope to meet those feats' prerequisites later!

Comment: Oh yeah, that's exactly what I meant. Thanks for clarifying, I'll be letting my group know that they can do it this way. In our game we have a low dexterity rogue (heh, dice is a funny thing that way) and he'll be happy to learn of this feature.